# Create a Dax Measure to get the average

Tags: dax, ssas-tabular

Hi I have a Fact table called FactUser and Dimension table called Target. Target Dimension contains the target values for each user. I need to get the average target value for each user using a measure in tabular. How can I do that? If target value is in the Fact table its no issue. Since the Target value is in a Dimension I'm bit confused to get the average over a user and over a day. Below show my tabular model

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the target value inside Fact table and got the average as below. I want to get the average over username and date.

```
var Pivoted= ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE(FactUser,DateDimension[Date],User[username])
        ,"AVERAGE TARGET",CALCULATE(sum(FactUser[Target]))

    )

return averagex(Pivoted,[AVERAGE TARGET])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you provided example and test cases with solution, it would be much easier.
If you need to perform aggregation on a field, then why it is not in the Fact Table?

According to [best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/star-schema), Power BI models should be designed as Star Schema and **in Star Schema measures are calculated only on Fact Tables**. So my suggestion in this case is not to solve the problem with DAX, but solve it by changing your Model.

However, you might try something like the following measure:

```
AVERAGEX('FactUser', RELATED('Targets'[Value])
```

Sources:
https://dax.guide/related/
https://dax.guide/averagex/

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer. it's because the target is changing over time and i thought its good to have the target in a dimension table!!! Since the key is in the fact table i thought i can get the average from there!!!am i wrong on this approach?

Comment: The star schema approach is correct but if you need to perform some aggregations on a specific field, I would suggest to keep that specific field on the fact table.

Comment: Hi I have edited my question can you take a look at it?

Comment: The question is not clear, please at least provide a simple example with real data and the expected result. Otherwise it is very difficult someone will be able to help you. However, in general the best practice for Power BI models is star schema and in Star Schema measures must be computed only on Fact Tables, there are several reasons for this statement.